Making a search location function through the Google Maps API
I don't know how to implement a search location function in my project based on the google maps API. The objective is to have the user type a location on the textview and clicks the button next it, it will display the results of the location such as where the location is and how many locations are there. I made a MapsFragment class that consists the basic functions of google maps. I'm trying to figure out how I can have the google maps app display location results based on the location the user types. Here is what I have so far in my MapsFragment,
class MapsFragment : Fragment(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMapsBinding
    private lateinit var requestPermissionLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<String>
    private var marker: Marker? = null
    private val locationViewModel: LocationViewModel by activityViewModels()
    private val sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()


    private val fusedLocationProviderClient by lazy {
        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(requireContext())
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        sharedViewModel.searchResultsCount.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { count ->
            binding.resultCount.text = "Search Results: $count"
        }


        return binding.root
    }


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)



        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        val mapFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
        requestPermissionLauncher =
            registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()) { isGranted ->
                if (isGranted) {
                    getLastLocation()
                } else {
                    // if should show rationale, show it
                    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                        showPermissionRationale {
                            requestPermissionLauncher.launch(ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private fun getLastLocation() {
        //fused location last location with addOnFailureListener and addOnCanceledListener listeners added
        fusedLocationProviderClient.getCurrentLocation(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, null)
            .addOnSuccessListener { location: Location? ->
                location?.let {
                    val currentLocation = LatLng(it.latitude, it.longitude)
                    updateMapLocation(currentLocation)
                    addMarkerAtLocation(currentLocation, "Current Location")
                    //zoom in
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15f))
                }
            }
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap.apply {
            setOnMapClickListener { latLng ->
                addOrMoveSelectedPositionMarker(latLng)
            }
        }

        when {
            hasLocationPermission() -> getLocation()
            shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) -> {
                showPermissionRationale {
                    requestPermissionLauncher.launch(ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                }
            }
            else -> requestPermissionLauncher.launch(ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        }
        //Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        // val sydney = LatLng(-34.0, 151.0)
        //mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"))
        // mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney))
    }


    private fun getLocation() {
        // Log.d("MapsActivity", "getLocation() called.")
        fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener {
                location: Location? ->
            location?.let {
                //   val userLocation = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)
                //   updateMapLocation(userLocation)
                //   addMarkerAtLocation(userLocation, "My Location")

                val Colorado = LatLng(38.0, -105.7)
                updateMapLocation(Colorado)
                addMarkerAtLocation(Colorado,"Some Nerd")
            }
        }

    }
    //zoom factor 2- 21
    private fun updateMapLocation(location: LatLng) {
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location, 9f))
    }

    private fun addMarkerAtLocation(
        location: LatLng, title: String, markerIcon: BitmapDescriptor? = null)
            = mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().title(title).position(location).apply {
        markerIcon?.let { icon(markerIcon) }}
    )

    private fun getBitmapDescriptorFromVector(@DrawableRes
                                              vectorDrawableResourceId: Int): BitmapDescriptor? {
        val bitmap = ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(),
            vectorDrawableResourceId)?.let { vectorDrawable ->
            vectorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0,
                vectorDrawable.intrinsicWidth, vectorDrawable.intrinsicHeight)
            val drawableWithTint = DrawableCompat
                .wrap(vectorDrawable)
            DrawableCompat.setTint(drawableWithTint,
                Color.MAGENTA)
            val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                vectorDrawable.intrinsicWidth, vectorDrawable.intrinsicHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
            )
            val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
            drawableWithTint.draw(canvas)
            bitmap
        }?: return null
        return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap)
            .also { bitmap?.recycle() }
    }

    //this will move the marker to a spot you click on the map and then press the button
    private fun addOrMoveSelectedPositionMarker(latLng: LatLng) {
        view?.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button1)?.setOnClickListener {
            if (marker == null) {
                marker = addMarkerAtLocation(latLng, "Vehicle Location",
                    getBitmapDescriptorFromVector(R.drawable.mini_me_location)
                )
            } else {
                marker?.apply { position = latLng } }
        }
        locationViewModel.updateParkingLocation(latLng.toString())
    }

    private fun hasLocationPermission() =
//check if ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission is granted
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED



    private fun showPermissionRationale(
        positiveAction: () -> Unit
    ) {
        AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
            .setTitle("Location permission")
            .setMessage("We need your permission to find your current position")
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok) { _, _ ->
                positiveAction()
            }
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel) { dialog, _ ->
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
            .create().show()
    }

I tried asking ChatGPT and Github copilot about it, but the answers they gave me wasn't helpful.
